# ADB pull iteratively

Tags: android, powershell, adb

The title is probably poorly worded, but essentially my friend's Galaxy S6 keeps restarting after being started up for about 30 seconds due to the error: `System UI has stopped working`

I'm trying to recover all of the pictures contained within the directory `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/` but the phone restarts after I copy around 80 of them using `adb pull /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/`. How can I copy 80 at a time and then sleep for say 20 seconds, and pull the next 80?

Comment: You have been around long enough to know that StackOverflow is not the right place to get help with your end-user problems. But you can start developing a solution for your problem (a basic script in your case) by yourself and then ask for help with the problems you faced while programming.

Comment: @AlexP. I thought maybe there was some other way to use `adb pull` with arguments but I'm assuming there isn't based off of your input. I posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up coming with was this:

Get a list of all the files in said directory, then iterate through a number of them, if the copying fails due to the device restarting, then wait a second and try again. If the file is already copied, skip that file.

```
$outputDirectory = "C:\Temp\RecoveredPictures"
$amount = 100
adb shell find /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera -type f > C:\Temp\PictureNames.txt

$files = Get-Content C:\Temp\PictureNames.txt

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $files.Length; $i++) {
    $file = $files[$i]

    $fileName = $file.Split("/")[-1]

    if (Test-Path $outputDirectory\$fileName) {
        continue
    }

    Write-Host "File name is $file"
    adb pull $file $outputDirectory\$fileName

    if ($error[0].ToString() -like "error: device '(null)' not found") {
        $i--
        sleep 1
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens with the file when the phone restarts in the middle of transfer?

Comment: Then the error `error: device '(null)' not found` occurs and it sleeps until the error is not found, repeatedly trying to copy that file it failed to copy. Some files however get corrupted if it's in the middle of a transfer and that is not taken care of by the script. I had to manually go through and make sure they weren't corrupted and delete the ones that were and re-copy. No way I could easily verify whether the files had copied successfully or not.

Comment: at least you could have `find` print you the file sizes along with the names and check those as well - `find -L /sdcard/DCIM/Camera -type f -exec stat -c '%s %n' {} \;`